# How to import data from json file to mongodb atlas collection

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I wanted to import data to my collection in mongodb atlas, and I was following the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/beta/import-export/  but there is no "ADD DATA" and I don't know if Im using some other version or Im doing something else wrongly. 
I need to import whole file which is json array.

Answer (score 3):

The docs you referenced are for a future version of Compass. If you want to import from [EJSON at the command line](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#json-format) you can use [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Here's the simplest syntax, but there are many variations possible.

`mongoimport --db=users --collection=contacts --file=contacts.json`